# Google Maps API V 3 Referer Configuration

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hoping you are ok.

If you have the following URL:

http://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com//pruebas/personales/plantillas/alpha-01/templatesViewer.php?cdPlantilla=1

https://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com//pruebas/personales/plantillas/alpha-01/templatesViewer.php?cdPlantilla=1

How should you configure it in the Google APIs Console?

Have tryied several configurations but without success.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this seems to be working:

http://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com/pruebas/personales/plantillas/*

https://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com/pruebas/personales/plantillas/*

http://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com/pruebas/personales/plantillas/alpha-01/*

https://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com/pruebas/personales/plantillas/alpha-01/*

http://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com//pruebas/personales/plantillas/alpha-01/templatesViewer.php?cdPlantilla=*

https://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com//pruebas/personales/plantillas/alpha-01/templatesViewer.php?cdPlantilla=*

Thanks anyway :)